# how to access the MFT server using sas

Tags: unix, sas, sftp

Do we have any method in SAS to connect to MFT SERVER to access the files
as it can be possible in SAS to connect to SFTP using the below code.

filename myfile sftp '/users/xxxx/test.dat' host="unixhost1";

Comment: I'd guess not.  MFT seems to have many different incompatible implementations.  What vendor's MFT server are you trying to connect to?